# Curly brackets in moodle.sty

Tags: xml, moodle

I would like to have some curly brackets as delimiters of a set in latex type for a question, using `moodle.sty` package. Something like

```
\\[\big\\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon y\geq x\big\\}.\\]
```

When the `XML` is generated, it contains `\big{` and `\big}`, condidering `\\{` as escape character for `{`. Putting `\\\\{` makes latex see a linebreak command. Does anyone know how to fiz this?

Thanks in advance, Alexandre.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand exactly the problem you run into.

Maybe you could give a try to version 0.8 of `moodle`, published on CTAN, or the [development version](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/). Some issues with character escaping have been addressed, like [this one](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/issues/55).

Comment: Can you please consider publishing the newest version of your package on CTAN?

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution to your problem? I have exactly the same one.

For example, I'm trying to create a question like this:

```
Soit \(A\) le sous-ensemble de \(\mathbb{R}\) d\'efini par \(\displaystyle A=\Bigl\{x>0\,:\,\cos\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}\Bigr)>0\Bigr\}\).
```

But the some backslashes are missing in the xml file, and some extra-spaces are added. Here is the xml output :

```
Soit \(A\) le sous-ensemble de \(\mathbb {R}\) d&eacute;fini par \(\displaystyle A=\Bigl {x>0\,:\,\cos \Bigl (\frac {1}{x}\Bigr )>0\Bigr }\).
```

Extra-spaces have been added between "\mathbb" and "{R}", "\cos" and "\Bigl", "\frac" and "{1}", ... , and backslashes before "{" and "}" escaped.

Comment: Hi there! In fact I couldn't manage to solve this yet. The solution was to migrate to a bit more complex and powerful alternative: R+Swave+exams packages. There I write just a piece of latex and some R code to generate random data and hence several clones of the same question. In the same file I write solutions in terms of that parameters and voilà: a XML file to be uploaded to Moodle! You can also use a simpler markup language that doesn't require any TeX/LaTeX with exams package too. Hope it helps you as much as it helped me! Keep in touch!